# Ratchet not working on WebServer

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

i am using ratchet on server, everything works fine till telnet in documentation.

But when i use ws://localhost:8080, the connection is not getting established for some reason. I am using LEMP stack.

Comment: You correctly setup websockets in nginx?

Comment: i have setup nginx for reverse proxy of 127.0.0.1:8080 to listen at 8020 and in my javascript i have added ws://myip:8020
still no luck